# ActiveRecord: Load just single association from a has_many based on the parent record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an `Item` model, than has a `Category`, is assigned to a `Location`, and which has a `Responsible` (optional).

[image]

Then on a `Category`, you can too define multiple `default_responsibles`.

- A general one, if there is no location given
- One for a specific location (and which has preceedence over the general one).
  The idea here is, that if no responsible is given on the Item, it automatically pulls the correct from the category.

So here is the challenge. On the index page, where I display all items, including the responsible, how do I make a efficient query, properly eager_loading / preloading the right responsible (the one for the location - or if missing - the general one) on the category?

Database used: Postgresql

Comment: Add tag for database platform.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your model code, but I think you can do something like:

```
class Item
  has_one :responsible
  has_one :default_responsible, through: :category
```

Controller:

```
  def index
    @items = Item.all.includes(:responsible).includes(category: :default_responsible)
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#nested-associations-hash

Comment: If you look at the image, you‘ll see the model code. The challenge is on how to select the correct default responsible based on the item‘s location, if a category can have multiple default_responsible (hence for each location differently)